# performance issue with sp large parameters in ado.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-performance

The customer sends us a large message (e.g. xml message) and we need to save it into the database.

What we found is that when the message becomes larger, the time to pass the parameter to sp belongs long.

One message is around 500kb and we need to save it in database. From trace, we can see that the sp take 0-10ms to run. But from our c# code (a winform example), it takes around 2-3 seconds to finish.

We tried to run the c# code on sql server to remove the network issue, but the duration is almost the same.

Seems sql server has problems with large parameter.

Does anyone experienced this before?

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you parse the XML as parameter? Post some code from .net and sql

Comment: doesn't matter if the parameter is xml or varchar(max). both take around 2-3 seconds for the c# call to finish. The trace always show 10-20ms

Comment: What you if add a RETURN statement in the  Stored Procedure in the top just after it received your Paremter? That way you can see if it is the code or simply the parameter there is the issue.

Comment: did that. the trace shows 0ms, but still take c# side 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Can you add your c# code?